# Route + Render + Redirect with react-router-dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I just took over a React project from one of my colleague but I cannot understand the logic in the code below.

```
      content = <Switch>
        <Route path="/login" exact component={LoginPage} />
        <Route render={() => { return <Redirect to="/login" />; }} />
      </Switch>
```

I know how to use Route with `Component`, with `Render`, but `Render` with `Redirect`, first time I saw it.

Thanks

Comment: There is absolutely no need to call Redirect within render you could simply have it placed directly instead of Route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be just another way of just saying:

```
<Redirect path='*' to='/login' />
```

Since it is inside a `<Switch>`, and after any `<Route>`, it will always match (if nothing above it got matched) and get rendered.

When the `Redirect` component gets rendered, it does its job of redirecting to the page specified in the `to` prop.

I found that out by doing some reading of the source code. If you're interested, there's a bit of indirection, but basically the Redirect component renders a Lifecycle component which will call `method` with the `location` provided as soon as it's mounted.

`method` is set like this:

```
const method = push ? history.push : history.replace;
```

And that's done like that because apparently the `<Redirect>` component can take `push` as a boolean prop, to set the behaviour of how the redirect is actually achieved.

---

Redirect component source https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/Redirect.js

Lifecycle component source: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/modules/Lifecycle.js

Comment: Whether or not this is good practice to do like that, I don't know. As far as I can tell, there is not a big difference in the final result.

However, for the reader and for maintainability, this might be a bit confusing.